# Why does this ClassCastException regarding Generics in Java appear?

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

... and how to fix it?

I receive following error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
> java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
>    at *.model.communication.GsonStream.createRequest(GsonStream.java:1)
>    at *.client.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:26)
>    at *.client.HttpClient.main(HttpClient.java:33)
> ```

The error appears underneath the line with the comment

```
HttpStream jos = new GsonStream(connection);
//...
List reqPairList = new LinkedList<Pair<String, String>>();
reqPairList.add(new Pair("username", "uname"));
reqPairList.add(new Pair("passwort", "123"));

// Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
jos.createRequest(reqPairList);
```

And the called method and class looks as follows:

```
public class GsonStream
    implements HttpStream<Class<? extends Serializable>> {
    //...
    public void createRequest(Class<? extends Serializable> obj)
        throws Exception {
        //...
    }
}
```

I have no explanation for the error especially because Pair and LinkedList implementing Serializable also every Element of Pair is forced to implement it. (Pair is a selfdefined class)

Comment: GsonStream isn't correctly implemented, you shouldn't have those references to `Class`

Comment: `java.util.LinkedList` is indeed not castable to `java.lang.Class`, this exception is entirely valid.

Comment: I would like to constraint the unconstraint E from HttpStream to only classes that implement Serializable how can I fix it this way?

Comment: how do you expecting a `LinkedList` to cast in a `Class` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My lack in experience led to this error...
fix:

```
public class GsonStream<E extends Serializable>
        implements HttpStream<E> {
    //...
    public void createRequest(E obj)
            throws Exception {
        //...
    }
}
```

And everything works just fine.